# Compiled OK but NoClassDefFoundError when running

Tags: java

I'm trying to send an email using JavaMail API.
I have jdk 1.5 installed in my home directory from self-extracting binary. I'm on Ubintu 9.10

I compile the program using the next command:

~/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/javac -classpath ~/jdk1.5.0_22/jre/lib/javamail-1.4.3/mail.jar:~/jdk1.5.0_22/jre/lib/jaf-1.1.1/activation.jar hw.java

It compiles OK. As you can see I have specified the path to mail.jar and activation.jar
Now I try to run the app using the next command:

~/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java -classpath ~/jdk1.5.0_22/jre/lib/jaf-1.1.1/activation.jar:~/jdk1.5.0_22/jre/lib/javamail-1.4.3/mail.jar:. HelloWorldApp

I get an exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address

Why can it find classes when compiling and cannot do it when running?
How to correctly run my app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class should come from your `mail.jar`. I'm not sure your classpath is being parsed properly. The tilde (~) is a shell function and needs expanding before being sent to the Java process. Have you tried removing the ~ and replacing with `/home/{whatever}` ? I suspect that's the issue.

Comment: the class comes from mail.jar, not activation

Comment: Yes, you're right. I replaced ~ and it worked fine.
Though it compiled ok with ~

Comment: I note your classpath is reversed between the compilation and run scenarios. Not sure if that makes a difference...

Comment: No differenece. Only that it complains about some class in activation.jar rather than in mail.jar