# package org.apache.commons.httpclient does not exist import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*; While compiling Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile my Java program from the terminal and I get the following errors:

```
~/Desktop/test/myapp/HTTPRequest.java:3: error: package org.apache.commons.httpclient does not exist
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
^
~//Desktop/test/myapp/HTTPRequest.java:4: error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
                                  ^
~//Desktop/test/myapp/HTTPRequest.java:5: error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
                                  ^
~//Desktop/test/myapp/HTTPRequest.java:6: error: package org.apache.http does not exist
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
                      ^
~//Desktop/test/myapp/HTTPRequest.java:7: error: package org.apache.http does not exist
import org.apache.http.*;
^
~//Desktop/test/myapp/HTTPRequest.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        ^
  symbol:   class CloseableHttpClient
  location: class HTTPRequest
~//Desktop/test/myapp/HTTPRequest.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable HttpClientBuilder
  location: class HTTPRequest
~//Desktop/test/myapp/HTTPRequest.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        ^
  symbol:   class HttpGet
  location: class HTTPRequest
~//Desktop/test/myapp/HTTPRequest.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
                          ^
  symbol:   class HttpGet
  location: class HTTPRequest
~//Desktop/test/myapp/HTTPRequest.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
        ^
  symbol:   class HttpResponse
  location: class HTTPRequest
10 errors
```

My Java code is like this:

```
package test.myapp;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class HTTPRequest {

    private static String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private static String ACCEPT_HEADER = "Accept";
    private static String CONTENTTYPE_HEADER = "Content-type";
    private static String APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json";

    public static void getRequest() throws Exception {
        String url= "";
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

        get.setHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "==");
        get.setHeader(ACCEPT_HEADER, APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

        System.out.println("Response is : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            getRequest();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("recvd an error: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        }

    }


}
```

I am trying to compile my Java program in this way:

```
javac -cp ".;~/Desktop/test/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;~/Desktop/test/httpclient-4.3.4.jar" ~/Desktop/test/myapp/HTTPRequest.java
```

I have tried with only 3.1 and only 4.3.4 jar files as well, but I still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually 3 issues:

1. You don't have [**httpcore**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore) in your classpath which is actually the library that your program refers to. You only need `httpcore` and `httpclient` in your classpath, you can get rid of `commons-httpclient`.
2. You use **semicolons** as separator in your classpath while your are supposed to use **colons** on any os but windows. We use semicolons only on windows os.
3. The tilde (~) cannot be used to define your classpath, you need to provide the full paths instead, [more information in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1779197/1997376). I quote:

> The tilde (~) is a shell function and needs expanding before being
>   sent to the Java process